# C# Why isn't this variable set if it's set?

Tags: c#, variables, static-methods

Please, help. Cannot solve it tacking into account my lack of programming knowledge.

```
 public static void FileOutput(string path, bool rewrite, List<int> NumberOfWords)
{
    StreamWriter OutPath;
    try
    {
        OutPath = new StreamWriter(path, rewrite);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfWords; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            OutPath.Write(NumberOfWords[i]);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    OutPath.Close();
}
```

Comment: Screenshots are unpleasant :( It would be nice if you could actually paste in your code.

Comment: You can paste and format your code here, please remove that image and try to play with the SO text editor

Comment: What are you asking exactly?  More details are needed.

Comment: Path is probably invalid, check if it is catching an exception.

Comment: Because its not set under all conditions, if your Try throws an exception it'll continue underneath with the for loop where Outpath will be null. That for loop should be inside the Try...Catch statement under the outpath assignment.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder it should be compile time error/warning, I doubt OP get that far... But without actual error message and code this post likely get closed as "debugging help need to show code, expected behavior and error message".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you actually set your OutPath variable within the try-catch. That means your variable is only set within the scope of the try-catch. try this instead

```
 public static void FileOutput(string path, bool rewrite, List<int> NumberOfWords)
{
    StreamWriter OutPath;
    try
    {
        OutPath = new StreamWriter(path, rewrite);

        for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfWords; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                OutPath.Write(NumberOfWords[i]);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    OutPath.Close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect.  Scope is where you declare your variable not where you define it...but moving the loop into the try{} is the correct approach, so not knocking you down.

Comment: @KevinNelson can you give me the correct terminology so I can correct it. I always mess up my terms...

Comment: I'm horrible on terminology myself...but what you're trying to avoid is a null-reference exception where OutPath isn't defined...not becasue of block scope but because of an error...and because his catch() essentially just ignores the error, it goes on as if it is a valid StreamWriter.